# How to write a regex to match a string that has the word 'error' but not 'info'?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have two strings `a` and `b` here:

```
irb(main):022:0> a
=> "[:error] [pid 10101:tid 139953357145856] 2015-03-15 20:33:44,848 pid  10101 tid 139953357145856 INFO     env      Using"

irb(main):023:0> b
=> "[:error] [pid 10101:tid 139953357145856] 2015-03-15 20:33:45,712 pid  10101 tid 139953357145856 ERROR     env      Using"
```

I want to write a regex that can ignore `a` and match `b`.

In string `a`, ':error' is followed by 'INFO'.

In the second string `b`, ':error' is followed by 'ERROR'

I have tried this

```
a.match(".*error.*(?!INFO).*")
```

But the regex will return match for both `a` and `b`

The use of `match` is a must because I am trying to pass the regex to a sensu script (https://github.com/sensu/sensu-community-plugins/blob/master/plugins/logging/check-log.rb#L189)

Comment: Is `"ERROR"` relevant?  That is, must `"error"` be followed by `"INFO"` or `"ERROR"`? If so, the question should be clarified and the title changed; if not, I suggest you delete the sentence, "In the second...by 'ERROR'.

Comment: `ERROR` is not relevant here. Some `:error` lines may contain stacktrace that are useful but do not carry the word `ERROR`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preceding `.*` should be placed inside of the lookahead assertion ...

```
.*error(?!.*INFO).*
```

[**Rubular**](http://rubular.com/r/HyTliirVGV) —
Also, I would consider using [**word boundaries**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can match 'error' twice instead.

```
a.match(".*error.*ERROR.*")
```

#### EDIT

As pointed out by [Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland), this will also match INFO log entries containing "ERROR" string inside as you can see below:

```
irb(main):035:0> "error INFO ERROR".match(".*error.*ERROR.*")
=> #<MatchData "error INFO ERROR">

irb(main):036:0> "error ERROR INFO".match(".*error.*ERROR.*") # <-- HERE
=> #<MatchData "error ERROR INFO">

irb(main):037:0> "error INFO Praesent quis nisl posuere.".match(".*error.*ERROR.*")
=> nil
```

It will also happen with your initial `regexp` - skipping errors that contain the INFO string, like you can see below too:

```
irb(main):048:0> "error INFO ERROR".match(".*error(?!.*INFO).*")
=> nil

irb(main):049:0> "error ERROR INFO".match(".*error(?!.*INFO).*")
=> nil

irb(main):050:0> "error INFO Praesent quis nisl posuere.".match(".*error(?!.*INFO).*")
=> nil
```

To avoid skipping or matching incorrect log entries I would rely in more parts of that string.

For that, getting your two initial samples, I would rely in the timestamp, check it out:

```
irb(main):055:0> "[:error] [pid 10101:tid 139953357145856] 2015-03-15 20:33:44,848 pid  10101 tid 139953357145856 INFO     env      Using ERROR".match(".*error(?!.*[0-9] INFO).*")
=> nil

irb(main):056:0> "[:error] [pid 10101:tid 139953357145856] 2015-03-15 20:33:44,848 pid  10101 tid 139953357145856 INFO     env      Using ERROR".match(".*error(?!.*[0-9] INFO).*")
=> nil

irb(main):057:0> "[:error] [pid 10101:tid 139953357145856] 2015-03-15 20:33:45,712 pid  10101 tid 139953357145856 ERROR     env      Using INFO".match(".*error(?!.*[0-9] INFO).*")
=> #<MatchData "[:error] [pid 10101:tid 139953357145856] 2015-03-15 20:33:45,712 pid  10101 tid 139953357145856 ERROR     env      Using INFO">

irb(main):058:0> "[:error] [pid 10101:tid 139953357145856] 2015-03-15 20:33:45,712 pid  10101 tid 139953357145856 ERROR     env      Using INFO".match(".*error(?!.*[0-9] INFO).*")
=> #<MatchData "[:error] [pid 10101:tid 139953357145856] 2015-03-15 20:33:45,712 pid  10101 tid
```

So, my final version would be: `".*error(?!.*[0-9] INFO).*"`.

Comment: I reckon it will work. But I also want to learn why the match ahead does not work.

Comment: You want no match when the string contains `"INFO"`: `"error INFO ERROR".match(".*error.*ERROR.*") #=>
 => #<MatchData "error INFO ERROR">`.

Comment: Good catch, it will get a few false positives if you have the string "ERROR" inside a "INFO" log entry.